Vert.x GRPC Client received failed future with error Invalid gRPC status null
I am using the new Vert.x GRPC implementation - vertx-grpc-server and vertx-grpc-client (v4.5.7). Below are the client and server code snippets -
Server:
...
GrpcServer grpcServer = GrpcServer.server(vertx).callHandler(ServiceGrpc.getDataMethod(), 
    request -> request.handler(functionCall -> {
        final Promise<FunctionResponse> promise = Promise.promise();
        functionCallHandler(functionCall, promise);
        
        promise.future().onComplete(response -> {
            FunctionResponse functionResponse = response.result();
            System.out.println(functionResponse.getPayload());
            request.response().end(functionResponse);
        });
   }));
...

Client:
...
JsonObject payload = <some json>;

GrpcClient grpcClient = GrpcClient.client(Vertx.getVertx());
grpcClient.request(SocketAddress.inetSocketAddress(8080, "grpc_server_host"),     ServiceGrpc.getDataMethod()).compose(request -> {
        request.end(FunctionRequest.newBuilder()
            .setPayload(payload.encode())
            .build());
        return request.response().compose(GrpcReadStream::last);
    }).onComplete(
        response -> {
            if(response.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("Response received from GRPC server: " + response.result().getPayload());
            } else {
                System.out.println("GRPC communication failed with error: " + response.cause().getMessage());
            }
        });
...

With running above code, I see that Server side is receiving the request fine and also printing the printing the response data. However, the client side is receiving a failed response future with error -
GRPC communication failed with error: Invalid gRPC status null
I've tried printing the stacktrace as well, however, it's not of much use either -
ExceptionStack:
io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Invalid gRPC status null

Any pointers on what may be going wrong? One point is that when I run both above client and server on my local machine, everything runs just fine. The above error is occurring when the client and server code is deployed on actual servers.
Expecting the GRPC client to receive the response as sent by the GrpcServer
